# PYTHON FUNCIONES CON CADENAS Y REEMPLAZAR

Tags: python, string, funciones

NECESITO AYUDA CON EL SIGUIENTE EJERCICIO. CUANDO LO CORRO NO SUCEDE NADA.

Escribir una función modCadena(cadena), que recibe una cadena y devuelve una nueva. La función debe reemplazar las vocales por un “*”, las consonantes difíciles (w,z,y, x) por un “+”

```
def modCadena(cadena):
    nueva=" "
    for ele in cadena:
        if vocales in ele:
            nueva= nueva+"*" 
    return nueva
    for ele in cadena:
        if dificil in ele:
            nueva=nueva+"+"
    return nueva

palabra=input("Ingrese un palabra: ")
vocales= "aeiouAEIOU"
dificil="wzyxWZYX"
total=modCadena(palabra)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución: Recorres la cadena examinando cada letra. Si corresponde, la transforma. Si no, la dejas tal cual. Finalmente, la agregas a la palabra de salida:

```
def modCadena(texto):
    nuevo = ''
    for letra in texto:
        if letra in "aeiouAEIOU":
            nuevo += '*'
        elif letra in "wxyzWXYZ":
            nuevo += '+'
        else:
            nuevo += letra
    return ''.join(nuevo)
```

Los problemas con el código original:

1. La forma correcta es `if letra in palabra`.
2. Tienes un `return` incondicional dentro del ciclo -> el ciclo se ejecuta sólo una vez.
3. Nunca agregas las letras no modificadas

#### Demo

```
def modCadena(texto):
    nuevo = ''
    for letra in texto:
        if letra in "aeiouAEIOU":
            nuevo += '*'
        elif letra in "wxyzWXYZ":
            nuevo += '+'
        else:
            nuevo += letra
    return ''.join(nuevo)

palabra=input("Ingrese un palabra: ")
total=modCadena(palabra)
print(total)
```

produce:

```
Ingrese un palabra: la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta
l* m*n* j*c*nt* s* h* p**st* *n* c*nt*

Process finished with exit code 0
```